# ¿Como actualizo el key y el value de un hash en Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Resulta que tengo un *hash*:

```
inventario = {"Notebooks"=> 4, "PC Escritorio"=> 6, "Routers"=> 10, "Impresoras"=> 6}
```

Necesito actualizar la información respecto a cualquier producto, y que el inventario se actualice.

Probé con `map`, `hashmap` y `put`, pero al parecer no estoy ocupándolos bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para actualizar el valor de una llave en un hash, simplemente asigna un nuevo valor directamente utilizando el método [Hash#[]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D); por ejemplo:

```
inventario = { "Notebooks"=> 4, "PC Escritorio"=> 6, "Routers"=> 10, "Impresoras"=> 6 }
#=> {"Notebooks"=>4, "PC Escritorio"=>6, "Routers"=>10, "Impresoras"=>6}
```

Para cambiar el inventario de `"Notebooks"` a `5`:

```
inventario["Notebooks"] = 5
#=> 5

inventario
#=> {"Notebooks"=>5, "PC Escritorio"=>6, "Routers"=>10, "Impresoras"=>6}
```

Dado que los valores son números, puedes utilizar `+` o `-`; por ejemplo, si vendes 2 `"Impresoras"` (disminución de inventario), podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
inventario["Impresoras"] -= 2
#=> 4

inventario
#=> {"Notebooks"=>5, "PC Escritorio"=>6, "Routers"=>10, "Impresoras"=>4}
```

Finalmente, puedes sustituir los valores por variables, suponiendo que vienen de otra sección de código en tu aplicación; por ejemplo:

```
producto = "Routers"
items_vendidos = 3

inventario[producto] -= items_vendidos
#=> 7

inventario
#=> {"Notebooks"=>5, "PC Escritorio"=>6, "Routers"=>7, "Impresoras"=>4}
```

Comment: Y si deseo ademas obtener el producto con mayor stock?

Comment: @UpsetGrade Utilizando `max_by`: `inventario.max_by { |_, v| v }`